# Data not getting deleted using API from the SQL Server in xamarin forms. HttpClient delete

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms

I'm developing a Xamarin Forms application where I have to delete the record from the database when the reset button is clicked. We have an API that does the action.

The code is as follows:

API code

```cs
[HttpDelete]
public Response ResetRecord(string pk)
{
    try
    {
        Response response = new Response();

        using (var ctxdel = new GDSEntities4())
        {
            var result = ctxdel.SpDeleteRecordOnReset(int.Parse(pk));

            if (result > 0)
            {
                response.Message = result.ToString();
                response.Status = 1;                        
            }
            else
            {
                response.Message = "0";
                response.Status = 0;
            }
        }

        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response res = new Response();
        res.Message = ex.Message;
        res.Status = 0;
        return res;
    } 
}
```

This is working when I check with postman. In the front end, the delete function is as follows:

```cs
public async Task DeleteRecFromDB(string pk)//(, bool isNewItem = false) 
{
    try
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        Response response = new Response();
        string url = "http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/GDS/ResetRecord?PK={pk}";               

        var responseData = await client.DeleteAsync(url);

        if (responseData.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string result = await responseData.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(result);

            var message = response.Message;
            var status = response.Status;

            await DisplayAlert("Success","Deleted from DB","OK");
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Failed", "Couldnt Delete from DB", "OK");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
        await DisplayAlert(LangResource.Message, LangResource.MsgWentWrong, LangResource.ok);
    }
}
```

The value `pk` is coming to that function `DeleteRecFromDB` but I can't find what the problem is. It is executing `Couldnt Delete from DB` part. The record is not getting deleted from the database. But the stored procedure and the API are working fine. I am not able to delete the record from the front end.

The response when checked in postman

```
{
    "Message": "0",
    "Status": 0
}
```

My stored procedure is as follows:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SpDeleteRecordOnReset]
    (@ID int)
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM ProfMst 
    WHERE PK = @ID
END
```

Comment: I have added the postman result. Is that what you meant?

Comment: i have added the postman result. Plese check!

Comment: I am getting `Message : "Input string was not in a correct format."` in the debug. And `Status : 0`

Comment: If you get an error about the input string, what parameter did you send? You keep passing it as a string but clearly it should be an integer. What is the *actual* parameter you pass to it?

Comment: i have converted it into integer in the API code. `int.Parse(pk)`

Comment: Yes, and my guess is that it is this conversion that fails with your "Input string was not in a correct format". That's why I'm asking what you're actually passing in `pk`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Please see my answer. I was on this track, too, but it's just been the `$` for string interpolation been missing.

Comment: So it was actually passing the string `{pk}`. Amazing what you can learn through debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `pk` is `123`, you are trying to emit the request

```
DELETE /api/GDS/ResetRecord?PK=123 HTTP/1.1
Host: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Anyway, the actual request you are sending is

```
DELETE /api/GDS/ResetRecord?PK={pk} HTTP/1.1
Host: xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

because you missed the `$` for [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) in the line

```cs
string url = "http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/GDS/ResetRecord?PK={pk}";
```

Hence `url` has the value `http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/GDS/ResetRecord?PK={pk}` instead of `http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/GDS/ResetRecord?PK=123`. You can easily fix this by changing the line to

```cs
string url = $"http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/api/GDS/ResetRecord?PK={pk}";
```